# How do I change the background color of a kml placemark description window in Python?

Tags: html, colors, window, kml, google-earth

I am working on the visualization of several points on Google Earth using a kml file.
To create the point I use

```
kml.newpoint(name='test', description='''<table><tr><td><img src="https://ehsw47mb2ee.exactdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/surface-pro-6.jpg?strip=all&lossy=1&ssl=1.jpg" style="width: 75vw; min-width: 100px;"/></td></tr><tr><td><br><font size="+2" font color="text">NAME</font><br><font size="-1" font color="grey">text</font><br><br><font size="+1" font color="black">text</font></table></td></tr></table>''', coords=[(60,55,100)])
```

The attached image shows the window that opens when you click on the item.
Does anyone know how I can change the background color of this window? (It should be black).
I'm not familiar with HTML and I would be grateful for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that adding a [CSS background-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) property to the parent would be enough.
So adding a style attribute to the `<table>` element would suffice:

```html
<table style="background-color: #000000">
```

Currently making use of the black colour code.

Comment: Where exactly does it need to be inserted? 
Unfortunately, It did not work for me

Comment: You should add the style tag I showed in the first and only `<table>` tag you encounter. I tested it for myself and it worked.